# How to put php code inside html tag?

Tags: php, html

I am confused how to print fname variable inside an html tag. Here is my code that takes the value of an input and I want to print that in p tag.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){     
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
First Name <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" Value="Submit" name="submit">
<p id="demo"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: add it to the value attribute in your first name input = `value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"`

Comment: `<p><?php echo $fname; ?></p>`

Answer (score 0):

use `<?php ?>`  and between these tags write your php code anywhere..
like

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
First Name <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $firstname?>">
<input type="submit" Value="Submit" name="submit">
<p id="demo"> <?php echo "this is php "; ?></p>
</form>
```